# Is there any possibility to turn off the Places API in the Google Cloud Console and not get an error?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

is there any possibility to turn off the Places API in the Google Cloud Console and not get an error while the customers write a query into the address field? We do not want to use any of the Places API features including Autocomplete so we decided to turn it off, but now if anyone starts typing into the address field gets an error message. Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need Google's Places API enabled on your project to be able to use any of its services (such as [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)). Otherwise you'll get errors as you mentioned.

If you turned it off due to costs, note that there are ways to lower them (check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59110891/11742502)).

If you want to turn it off for good and allow users to type their address into a text field that doesn't use Google's Autocomplete widget (and hence not get errors), then you'll need to locate and remove your Maps API script and/or your Autocomplete implementation from your source code.

E.g. see the below example code which creates an Autocomplete object and attaches it to an input element.

```
<input id="autocomplete"
         placeholder="Enter your address"
         type="text"/>

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
```

Hope this helps!